# jquery mobile no styling on checkboxes after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use an ajax call to get a list of items from a json array and put them into a list of checkboxes. The items load in fine but they have no jquery mobile styling on them.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: "https://evalue.internationaldelivers.com/service_kb_cust/OCCAPI/Mobile/json/f9496ab3c3764fd0ae201de76c71608f/OCC_GetFiltersObj",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: 'application/json',
               crossDomain: true,
               async: true,
               cache: false,
               timeout: 30000,
               success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    for (var i=0, len=data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust.length; i < len; i++) {
                        $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-2' id="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+" class='custom'/>")
                        $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<label for="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+">"+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName+"</label>")
                    }
                },
                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    // Indicate complete
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // Assert an error

                }
            });
        });
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call trigger("create") on checkbox parent element

so try this :

```
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                 for (var i=0, len=data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust.length; i < len; i++) {
                    $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-2' id="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+" class='custom'/>")
                    $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<label for="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+">"+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName+"</label>")
                  }

                  $("[type='checkbox']").closest("div").trigger("create");    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      for (var i=0, len=data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust.length; i < len; i++) {
          $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-2' id="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+" class='custom'/>")
          $("#filterpanel fieldset").append("<label for="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerID+">"+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerName+"</label>")
      }

      $("#filterpanel fieldset").trigger("create");
```